# how to implement row level summmary function in informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

Can someone please explain me how to implement the following logic in informatica. but Not with source qualifier with other transformations inside the mapping.

SUM(WIN_30_DUR) OVER(PARTITION BY AGENT_MASTER_ID ORDER BY ROW_DT ROWS BETWEEN 30 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)

Basically this is sql(oracle) level requirement but i want at informatica level.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Aggregator to calculate sums groupped by AGENT_MASTER_ID and self-join it on AGENT_MASTER_ID. Make sure to have the data sorted and use 'sorted input' property for aggregator - it will also be mandatory for a self join.